# Function expecting arguments and returning a pointer to a void function

Tags: c++, pointers

I have several void-functions that do some important things in my code.

```
void function1(Myclass class1, int myvar)
{
   // do some stuff
}

void function2(Myclass class1, int myvar)
{
   // do some other stuff
}

// ... maybe some more similar functions
```

I want to create a function that would return a pointer to any of these functions depending on arguments I pass. I don't know how to do it. I want to have something like

```
void* choosefunction(int i, int j)
{
   if (i == j) return (void*)function1;
   else return (void *)function2;
}
```

Then I would just call them by this pointer.

```
void *(*ptrProcFunc)(int,int); 
ptrProcFunc = &choosefunction;
(*ptrr)() = ptrProcFunc(i,j);
ptrr(class1,myvar);
```

How to do it correctly? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`typedef` is your friend.

```
typedef void (*func_ptr)(Myclass, int);

func_ptr choosefunction(int i, int j)
{
   if (i == j) return &function1;
   else return &function2;
}
```

Then:

```
func_ptr ptrr = choosefunction(i,j);

ptrr(class1,myvar);
```

Comment: Another option is to not use pointer typedefs, IMO code is easier to read when there is always a `*` in any pointer declaration

Comment: If C++11 or higher is available, I preffer the alias form: `using func_ptr = void(Myclass, int);` I think it is way clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

// Typedef for convenience, called "fcn".
typedef void(*fcn)(int, int);

// You could also use c++11's std::function, which is easier
// to read than function pointers.
typedef std::function<void(int, int)> modern_fcn;

void func1(int a, int b) {
    std::cout << "func1" << std::endl;    
}

void func2(int a, int b) {
    std::cout << "func2" << std::endl;
}

// This returns our typedef'd function pointer.
fcn pick(int i, int j) {
    if (i == j) {
        return &func1;
    } else {
        return &func2;
    }
}

int main()
{
  // Should call func1.
  pick(1,1)(3, 5);

  // Should call func2.
  pick(1,2)(3, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

- You can use an using declaration to introduce an *alias* for your type:

  ```
  using func_ptr = void (*)(Myclass, int);
  using choose_ptr = void *(*)(int,int);

  // ...

  func_ptr choosefunction(int i, int j) {
      if (i == j) return &function1;
      else return &function2;
  }

  // ...

  choose_ptr ptrProcFunc = &choosefunction;
  func_ptr ptrr = ptrProcFunc(i,j);
  ptrr(class1,myvar);
  ```
- You can use the `auto` specifier and that's all (C++14):

  ```
  auto choosefunction(int i, int j) {
      if (i == j) return &function1;
      else return &function2;
  }

  // ...

  auto ptrProcFunc = &choosefunction;
  auto ptrr = ptrProcFunc(i,j);
  ptrr(class1,myvar);
  ```
- You can use the `auto` specifier and the trailing type (C++11):

  ```
  auto choosefunction(int i, int j) -> decltype(&function1) {
      if (i == j) return &function1;
      else return &function2;
  }

  // ...

  auto ptrProcFunc = &choosefunction;
  auto ptrr = ptrProcFunc(i,j);
  ptrr(class1,myvar);
  ```

  In this case, we exploit the fact that `function1` and `function2` have the same type.

Answer (score 1):

The (ugly) syntax is

```
void (*choosefunction(int i, int j))(Myclass, int)
{
   if (i == j) return &function1;
   else return &function2;
}
```

With `using` (or `typedef`), it becomes readable:

```
using F = void(Myclass, int);
using FPtr = void(*)(Myclass, int); // or using FPtr = F*;
```

And then

```
F* choosefunction(int i, int j);
```

or

```
FPtr choosefunction(int i, int j);
```

if you inline definition, you may in c++14 use simpler `auto`:

```
auto choosefunction(int i, int j) {
    if (i == j) return &function1;
    else return &function2;
}
```

Anyway, usage would be something like:

```
FPtr f = choosefunction(i, j);

f(myclass, myvar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion (and I've seen this in a lot of people learning C or C++)) is that those are not "void functions". At best you can say they are functions not returning anything (and if you are a bit more relaxed and abuse the language we can say they are functions returning void). They are **functions receiving a `Myclass` and an `int` arguments and returning nothing**.

The other answers show you how you can accomplish that. I strongly encourage you to use `using` instead of `typedef`, especially for a function type:

```
using func_ptr = void (*)(Myclass, int);
```

---

The source of the confusion (I think) is that you first learn variable declarations:

```
int a
```

and you learn that the type of the declared *entity* is named on it's left.

Then you learn functions and you write:

```
int sum(int a, int b)
```

And by (wrong) analogy you say: the *entity* being declared is `sum` so it's type must be what is written on it's left, i.e. `int`. So you say "sum is of type `int`" which is wrong and induces confusions like the one in you OP.

The type of `sum` is "function receiving two integers as parameters and returning an integer".

To help you shed your habit, write or at least think of functions in the new trailing return type declaration syntax:

```
auto sum(int a, int b) -> int
```